# Javascript change text based on textbox text works but then goes away

Tags: javascript, html

This works but then it disappears after like a second

```
function tfw() {
  var TFW = document.getElementById("TFW").value
  if (TFW == "mexicans") {
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<h1>worked!</h1>";
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

**Occasion:**

```
<input type="text" id ='TFW'><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="tfw();">
```

Comment: Which browser? You can't reference `event` as a global in all browsers, so I think you'll find that last line gives an error, you're not preventing the default submit button behaviour, so the form is submitting, causing the page to reload.

Comment: @nnnnnn the browser i am using for testing is FireFox

Comment: Can you please post the complete code.

Comment: @HectorBarbossa it works but not on fire fox and the complete code is https://pastebin.com/Fb5hkisv know of any way i can get it to work on fire fox and thanx for editing the format of my message i am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` and also get rid of `event.preventDefault()` to fix the issue.

Comment: That would change the behaviour - note that the function only tries to prevent the submission for the specified text value.

Comment: Thank you it works now me and my partner for our school project thank you alot.

Comment: @nnnnn the poor way i had it coded made the way he presented work perfectly with nothing else being needed to change some times being a bad programmer works out lol.